# What does "Considered for the Vacancy" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand this paragraph after taking an exam for USPS.

What does "to be considered for the vacancy" in this context mean?
Does it mean, I am not fit to become hired? or does it mean the opposite?

```
1. If you are under the age of 26.
If you are under the age of 26, you will continue to be considered for the vacancy for which you
have applied if you immediately register with the Selective Service System and submit to
HRSSC External Hiring at ***@***.gov written proof of such registration so that it is
received on or before the 10th calendar day from the date of my message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the example you provided, "considered for the vacancy could be replaced with "eligible" with no real difference in meaning. In other words, if you are under 26 you must be registered with selective service system in order to continue to be eligible for that position.